# Powershell: Checking for duplicate email in AD

Tags: powershell, validation, oop, active-directory, powershell-3.0

**Background:**
I'm trying to make a script that will see if a  new users email (`$email`) is the same as one already existing (which would cause an error). I have a very remedial understanding of objects so this is what I have so far (yes it is ugly):

```
$email = "smithj@company.com"   
$mailcheck = Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties * | ForEach-Object {$_.mail}
$mailcheck | ForEach-Object {if ($email -eq $_.mail){"$email = $($_.mail) - Matching email"}else{"$email = $($_.mail) - No duplicate email"}}
```

**Problem 1:** 
The script doesn't match emails. When I have a matching email in AD it doesn't recognize it.

**Problem 2:** When executing just the 2nd line, indexing doesn't work properly. While it looks like a consecutive list of emails, if a user doesn't have an email at all (blank) really it could be something like this:

```
smithj@company.com

johnsonj@company.com


robertsr@company.com
doej@company.com
```

So `$mailcheck[0]` returns `smithj@company.com` while `$mailcheck[1]` returns blank despite the list actually looking like this:

```
smithj@company.com    
johnsonj@company.com             
robertsr@company.com
doej@company.com
```

**Conclusion**: I really just need problem 1 solved but problem 2 peaked my curiosity. Thanks.

Comment: I'm writing up a proper answer but FYI doing `-Properties *` is a terrific way to significantly hamper the performance of `Get-ADUser`. The properties that return by default *never* need to be specified, you only need to specify properties that don't return by default if you need them (like `EmailAddress`)

Comment: That's a very good piece of information to know. Thank you.

Comment: I'll put this in my answer too, but you only need to use `-Properties` to specify properties you need to act on *later*. The `-Filter` parameter will be able to check any nondefault properties without needing to specify them in `-Properties`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are doing it above is *really* inefficient. `-Properties *` will return every property on the user, some properties are expensive in terms of processing power to return. Only use the properties you need. The properties returned by default without specifying that parameters do not need to be specified with `-Properties`, only additional nondefault properties. `-Filter *` will also match on literally any value for any field, effectively returning every `ADUser`, further increasing the resources required for your script to execute as you will now have to process every user to find any accounts matching that email.

Now that that's out of the way, here is a more efficient method to implement what you're asking:

```
# Set the email address to search for
$emailAddress = 'box@domain.tld'

# Get all users where the email address matches what is set above
# Force it as an array so you can treat it like one even if only
# one or zero users are returned
$adUsers = @( Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '${emailAddress}'" )

# Make sure no accounts were returned
# If there are, throw an error with the number of users and who they are
if( $adUsers ) {
  throw "Found $($adUsers.Count) users matching EmailAddress ${emailAddress}: $($adUsers.SamAccountName -join ', ')"
}
```

By using the filter to only match the specific email address, Powershell does not need to collect every single AD user in the system, or iterate over all of them to find a specific email address. This will take a long time to check, especially in larger environments, whereas filtering the returned objects based on email address (or on any other property) results in a faster operation and less data to sift through.

You can then check whether `$adUsers` contains anything (an array count of anything but `0` evaluates to `$True`, you could also use `if( $adUsers.Count -gt 0 )` as the condition), and if so, throw an error with more information as I do above.

### Update for comment question:

To answer your other question in the comment, "I didn't know what object to compare `$email` to", `EmailAddress` and `Mail` both look to be valid properties, but I don't know the difference between them. In my environment, both `Mail` and `EmailAddress` are populated with my email address, but have always used `EmailAddress` and haven't run into issues using that. Maybe one is deprecated and the other is new or something, but I'm not really sure.

There is also *yet another* property called `proxyAddresses` as well, which preliminary research shows that both `EmailAddress` and `Mail` are related to it, but I don't know much about it. It's not populated on my `ADUser` objects, so I can't poke around with it.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and very well explained. This helped me beyond the problem I was having. I am wondering if you could explain (or link) how the `${emailAddress}` part works, particularly the use of brackets, because part of my problem was I didn't know what object to compare `$email` to.

Comment: "${variableName}" is called String Delineation. It's mostly useful when you want to immediately follow a variable value with additional characters but don't want the additional characters to be interpreted as part of the variable name. I tend to prefer it though as it makes it clear where my string interpolation is. Here is some more info on it: https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-01-13-powershell-variable-substitution-in-strings/#delineation-with-braces

Comment: `"$($_adUsers.Count)"` is called Command Subsitution. The syntax is similar to String Delineation but allows you to specify an expression to be evaluated, the output of which becomes part of the string. with String Delineation, you can't access a property of a variable, which is why we use a substitution here. A more advanced example can be seen in the same `throw` line, where I join all `SamAccountName` values with a comma and trailing space.